# What is the difference between ガラクタ and ゴミ？

Tags: word-choice

I like to listen to NERU's Vocaloid songs, but I realized that several of his songs had two words translated the same way. Those are ガラクタ and ゴミ. I think ゴミ can be used to talk about taking garbage bags out to be taken, but in the means of the word "trash" alone, what is the difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trash is generally ゴミ but ガラクタ can mean reusable/recyclable materials like metal scraps, etc. like those you can see in a junkyard. Even ゴミ could be reusable depending on the person, but just trying to explain the general difference. One man's garbage is another man's treasure, so they say.

p.s.
I don't know who NERU is and what a Vocaloid song means.